# The difference between 'ADD' and 'DADD'

Tags: mips32, mips64

What is the difference between '`ADD`' and '`DADD`' `MIPS` instructions?

I know that '`DADD`' stands for Double Word Add but I do not know the difference between '`ADD`' and '`DADD`'.

Moreover, it appears that both instructions have the same syntax,

e.g.,

```
ADD R1, R0, R0
DADD R1, R0, R0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ADD` is the MIPS32 instruction, `DADD` is for MIPS64 where registers are 64-bits wide rather than 32.

Both instructions do exactly the same thing, they are used in different MIPS architectures, that's just it.